# Azure SendGrid gives Forbidden status code

Tags: azure-functions, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid service in Azure Function (C# code using API Key). I am getting the response status code as Forbidden. When I search for this issue, some links suggests that Single Sender Verification has to be completed. So I enter my official email ID. But I didn't received verification mail. Please anyone let me know how to get it verified. (I have raised support ticket. But no response).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a Single Sender first.
[image]

Then, click 'Resend Verification' button.
[image]

Finally, you will receive e-mail, click 'Verify Sender Identity' is ok.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. That is my issue. I was not received any verification mail.( I already mentioned in my Query). Do you have any idea whether any other good service available other than SendGrid and MailJet to send mail from Azure Function?

Comment: I have created the SendGrid Account from Azure Portal. There is no Marketing menu as like in your screenshot.

Comment: You can create account here https://sendgrid.com/. There is no other service to send mail.

Comment: I did that. From there I am able to Verify sender. I have simply followed the code given in "https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-csharp-code-example/". I am receiving the response status code "Accepted", but mails are not received. I have checked email activity. It showing as "Not Delivered". Do you have any idea, what could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: please refer to this [code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp#asynchronous).

Comment: I tried that sample code, but not received any mail.

Comment: What is your email activity, and check your junk email. It works fine on my side.

Comment: It showing as "Delivered" for official ID. But I didn't get any mail. Even checked junk mail. And for personal ID like GMail, it showing as "Not Delivered"

Comment: Actually those mails are blocked in my organization by marking it as "Phish" due to the policy type "AntiPhishPolicy". I am working with my organization network team. In the mean time, any one please tell me a solution for this issue.

Comment: The mails are blocked due to DMARC fail. Does the domain authentication will solve my issue? If so, some  three entries are created when I do domain authentication process. Please let me know what to do with that entries.